# rowspan not changing color in ide

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Why is my rowspan not working in VSC. My formatting seems correct, but it isn't changing colors even when I tab complete with a shortcut.

```
body>
    <h1>Heaviest Birds</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> rowspan="2"> Name</th>
                <th>average mass</th>
                <th> Animal </th>
                <th> rowspan Face </th>
```

Comment: Try like this: `<th rowspan="2">`

Answer (score 1):

You can't close the tag when you put a rowspan or colspan.
So do this: `<th> rowspan="2">` -> `<th rowspan="2">`

```html
    <h1>Heaviest Birds</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2"> Name</th>
                <th>average mass</th>
                <th> Animal </th>
                <th> rowspan Face </th>
```